# Shaving chest hair

Tags: men

Assalaam alaikum , I just have one important query regarding shaving hair..I am aware that shaving the armpits and private parts are mandatory but I was wondering whether it is permissible to shave the chest hair for men?

Thanks 
Shafiq Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (pbuh) said:

> “What is halaal is that which God has permitted in His Book, and what is haraam is that which God has forbidden in His Book, and what He has remained silent about is forgivable.” 
>   Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1726; 
>   classed as hasan by al-Albaani in
>   Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

While there are hadiths about pubic hair and facial hair etc. There are no verses or sahih hadiths which prohibits from shaving chest hair, therefore shaving chest hair is a matter of personal choice and not forbidden.

Hope that's the answer to your question.